# parsing value from a text field to the data base with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I created a simple text field form and a button on a webpage:

```
<input type="text" value="name"><button>click me</button>
```

and I created a short script in jquery:

```
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( "input" ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is to take the value written by user in the text field and after hitting the button - inserting taken value from text field to the database. I have database ready, but I've never connected with that through jquery, I only used php for that. Right now when I press the button, I get the "name" string inside the text field (instead of string typed before). How should I change the code to make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: have you heard of Ajax?

Comment: also you should `.val()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Jquery can't connect to your database. You could use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to post your form to a handler (could be a PHP script)  that does the database insert for you

Comment: Why you are not using ajax to save data into database

Comment: Ok guys, I get that I can take the data from there by using php (how?), but I'm not familiar with ajax yet :|

Comment: @randomuser2, See this link exactly what you want- http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="name" id="name">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me"/>
<script>
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  var text = $("#name").val();
 $.ajax({
        url: 'location.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    text: text
                },
                success: function(response) 
                {
                    alert("inserted");
                }
        });

});
</script>
```

it will just get the input value than you have to post it using ajax and using mysql you can insert the value to database

Comment: How would this insert data into a database?

Comment: Hey vivek, the code is fine for me, thanks for that :) could you just tell me how to move it further - I mean how exactly can I insert the data to the database with ajax? Could you show me some example?

Comment: @randomuser2 just updated code check it use it enjoy it and dont forget to right tick if it works

Comment: and then in my php code can I just use the variable:
$text = $_REQUEST['text']; ?

Comment: yes you can use $_REQEST or $_POST to get the posted data and use php and mysql to insert data

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue to use php to talk to the database and use 
jQuery.ajax(), or the .post() or .get() shorthand, to send the data to php. So:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $.post('myphpfile.php', { mytext: $('input').val() });
});
```

then in your php file:

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["mytext"] )
{
   $mytext = $_REQUEST['mytext'];

   // insert $mytext into database 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    data: $("input").val()
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved" );
  });
});
```

Comment: and then in my php code can I just use the variable: $text = $_REQUEST['text']; ? or what exactly is the name that I should pass in REQUEST[] ?

Comment: data: equals your POST query for ex, in js data: "myVar=myVal" and in php $got= $_POST["myVar"];

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong, but if I undersrood it correctly, I should use on php page: $text = $_REQUEST['input'] ?

Comment: You can set variable name whatever you want in query, then in php you get it as you setted in html. With form elements you can set <input name="myPhpVar" > and get $_POST["myPhpVar"], if you want to use multiple variables in array, you can set <input name="myPhpArray[myPhpVar]" > then get in php $_POST["myPhpArray"]["myPhpVar"] But with ajax you have to serialize form and send with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Use AJAX call to call you service and pass you value parameter along with that.

var val=$('#text').val();
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "value="+val,
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```